# Can I track files in two git repositories simultaneously?

Tags: git, symbolic-link

I've got two repositories set up for a class I teach, one outward-facing with demo and example code, and one to track changes I make to the class manual. I've written the manual in LaTeX [Listings package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/), so I can keep example code in a separate (complete) file. My first idea for keeping the code in both repositories is a symlink to a common directory, but I've been reading that symlinks are apt to cause problems with Git (only tracking the links, not what they point to). Is there any good way to do this efficiently and automatically?

Answer (score 1):

What about making a third repository for the common files, and then [submoduling](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) it into your other repos?